# extracting email address from exception message

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

In `python-social-auth`, when a user registers with an existing email address, an exception is raised.

I managed to catch this exception:

```
msg =   "%s" % exception
```

If I print `msg`, I get the following output:

```
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'email@id.com' for key 'email_UNIQUE'")
```

I would like to detect this exception and display a custom error message to the user, something like:

> This email id already exists please login with email@id.com or choose to sign in.

So my question is, how do I get only the email address from the exception message? Or is there any shortcut like `{{ exception.email }}` to get the email address in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use regular expression

```
import re

strs="""(1062, "Duplicate entry 'email@id.com' for key 'email_UNIQUE'")"""

email_id =re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", strs, re.DOTALL)[0]
print 'This email id already exists please login with {} or choose to sign in.'.format(email_id)
#output This email id already exists please login with email@id.com or choose to sign in.
```

Comment: that mean match all character in between quotes.'(.*?)'